# Queueing theory - one server and two queues with priority

Tags: queueing-theory

I want to study a scheduling scenario by using queuing theory.

This is the situation:

- one CPU with mean service time $1/μ$
- two infinite queues with arrival rate $λ$

  - queue B has priority over queue A, i.e if the CPU is executing a  job of A type, it stops (preemption) that job and executes (for all) the B job. Then if the B queue is empty it continues to execute the A jobs until a new B job/s arrives.

I would calculate some stability conditions, but I have never worked on systems like this.

If I would see the system as M/M/1 with only the queue with higher priority I could use $λ < \mu$ relation, but what about the queue A behaviour?

In the end, I have to do some simulations (with different parameters) and get some results about waiting times in the queues. I am doing some queuing theory modelling first to calibrate a bit the parameters of the system (inter-arr times and job tasks time, both exponential for both queues, CPU speed..)

I have read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835947/references-request-two-queue-one-server-model-with-pre-emptive-queue-priority) question, but it is slightly different for my case/

What can I do?

Comment: I think you are just describing a priority queuing system with preemption; see, e.g., [this link](https://www.netlab.tkk.fi/opetus/s383143/kalvot/E_priority.pdf). In terms of stability conditions, I believe it's just $(\lambda_A+\lambda_B)/\mu < 1$ since, in terms of stability, it doesn't matter which priority class the job came from.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 thank you for the reply! I have one other question: since the tasks have lengths that are exponentially distributed (one for A and one for B) and the CPU has a fixed clock. Should I consider different service time depending on the queue? $1/μ_A$ and  $1/μ_B$

Comment: Oh, if the service times are different for the different priority classes then the stability condition isn't as simple. If I recall, it's not too hard, but you'll find it when you look into the priority queuing literature.

Comment: I found some material about this. I am asking if, it Is correct to consider two serving time if I have task duration from two different distributions

Comment: Yes, but I don't remember the details.

Comment: Thanks, I will study mi notes and I will try to give an answer to the question, after your approval. If possible

Comment: I doubt I have the expertise to provide approval, but you can post.